# Link to Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, hyperlink

I'm developing a website in HTML and I would like to surround a postcode with a link so that when a user clicks on the postcode he is sent to google maps searching that postcode. Any advice how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: go to the map you want, copy the url. use the url as the link...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=POSTCODE">POSTCODE</a>
```

You mean like that?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Map Images API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) on Google. It's actually pretty straight forward.

> Static Maps API
>
> Add static maps, including terrain or satellite maps, to your web page or application. The Static Maps API supports custom styling, high resolution printing and displays, markers, and geometry.
>
> Read the developer documentation.

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```

Dev Documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index

Comment: I think OP just wants to link to the Google Maps site.

Comment: Yes I want to redirect to google maps using the postcode, not a map in the website

Answer (score 0):

Just put this type of link with q=postcode :

```
<a href="https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=YourPostCode" target="_blank">Go on maps </a>
```

example

```
<a href="https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=83210" target="_blank">Go on maps </a>
```

Enjoy